# What does the TableAdapter.Delete() method do?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

My lecturer gave us this piece of code to use when working with an SQL database in C#:

```
DataSetEmployeeTableAdapter.Delete(Convert.ToInt32(iDTextBox.Text), isTeachingPositionCheckBox.IsChecked);
```

The Employee table in our database contains the fields ID, FirstName, LastName, Position, Department, and IsTeachingPosition. I was curious about why we needed to tell the Delete() method whether IsTeachingPosition was true or false, as I'd think it should only need the primary key to delete an entry. I asked my lecturer and he had no idea, but when I looked into the code behind the Delete() method, it said this:

```
public virtual int Delete(int Original_ID, global::System.Nullable<bool> Original_IsTeachingPosition) {
        this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters[0].Value = ((int)(Original_ID));
        if ((Original_IsTeachingPosition.HasValue == true)) {
            this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters[1].Value = ((object)(0));
            this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters[2].Value = ((bool)(Original_IsTeachingPosition.Value));
        }
        else {
            this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters[1].Value = ((object)(1));
            this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters[2].Value = global::System.DBNull.Value;
        }
        global::System.Data.ConnectionState previousConnectionState = this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Connection.State;
        if (((this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Connection.State & global::System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) 
                    != global::System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)) {
            this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Connection.Open();
        }
```

I saw that it checked whether the checkbox is null or has a value, and performs a different operation on each condition (filling Parameters[1] with either an object of 0 or 1), so I asked my lecturer and he still had no idea. This led me to research and find that the Delete() method requires every column to be given to it, which means that somehow the (object)(0) code must be filling in the missing columns.

I could not find anything further on this (possibly as it was auto-generated code), but I am curious as to what this code does and why it was necessary to put in the primary key and checkbox, but not the rest of the data.

Comment: I think you should look at what the Delete command actually does to understand why the code is this way.

Comment: Interesting why the `this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters[].Value` has varying boxing/unboxings